# Mongoose first sort and limit by one property, then sort by another property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I get those n dataset with the highest *count* but return them sorted by name?

I tried the following, but that does not work.

```
db.Foo
      .find()
      .sort({'count': -1})
      .limit(n)
      .sort({'name': 1}) // does not work
      .exec(...);
```

Is there any other solution besides manually sorting the returned json array?

Such like subqueries in SQL?

```
SELECT *
FROM
( SELECT *
  FROM Foo
  ORDER BY count DESC
  LIMIT n
) AS tmp
ORDER BY name ASC ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever a query has multiple steps like this, an [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline) pipeline is typically what you need:

```
db.Foo.aggregate([
    // Sort all the doc on count, descending
    {$sort: {count: -1}},
    // Take the first n of those
    {$limit: n},
    // Resort those n docs on name
    {$sort: {name: 1}}
]).exec(...);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Excellent answer, this also work to display for instance the x last lines of logs : you'll need to sort by date in descending order, apply the limit then sort the resulting list in ascending order, hence performing two sorting operations along the same property.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add both conditions in one sort

```
db.Foo
  .find()
  .sort({'count': -1,'name': 1})
  .limit(n)
  .exec(...);
```

Comment: No, thats not what I need. I want to first sort, then take the n fist entries and then sort again.